# exim4, dovecot, gmail

Tags: gmail, tomcat6

We are trying to set up a mail server for outgoing mails using gmail. The application is based on java. in config file smtp.gmail.com and port 587 is added same port is added in exim4-config file. But when mail is checked it throws an error as "com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException:530 5.7.0 must issue a STARTTLS command first.

Can someone pl. help to sort out this error. Do we need to add any configuration in our tomcat/conf/server.xml file. If mail is sent directly through squirrelmail client it delivers in gmail account but the above error comes through tomcat. Anyhelp is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Usual smtp mail server communicate on port 25. In your configuration you use secure port 587 for smtp witch is for tls secure connection, but do not config TLS.

I find manual for exim configuration [here](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-encrypted_smtp_connections_using_tlsssl.html)

Try maybe help

Comment: this link seems quiet complicated. is there a simple solution to the above problem.

Comment: You can not use smtp.google.com without ssl or tls.

Comment: pl. guide me how to use smtp.google.com with tls

Comment: Try with this link https://wiki.debian.org/GmailAndExim4